# I need to reset y inside the loop before the if statements, then check the count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello im trying to make this loop count when it finds a certain object then once it finds all 3 it executes the final line. However when i run the code as is the game does not start. Im assuming this is because once it cant find one object it counts that 3 times. So i believe the best way to fix this would be to reset y inside the loop before the if statements, then check the count. Im not exactly sure how to go about this. Any ideas of how i can make this happen. any help would be greatly appreciate it.

```
    void Start() {
    y = 0;
    StartCoroutine(checkTurrets());
}

IEnumerator checkTurrets() {
    while (true) {
        y = 0;
        if (GameObject.Find("right") != null) {} else {
            y++;
        }
        y = 0;
        if (GameObject.Find("left") != null) {} else {
            y++;
        }
        y = 0;
        if (GameObject.Find("bottom") != null) {} else {
            y++;
        }
        if (y == 3) {
            y++;
            SphereCollider sc = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof (SphereCollider)) as SphereCollider;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh what are you trying to do with that?

Comment: You're *constantly* setting `y` to `0`.  How would it *ever* equal `3`?  Why is this an infinite loop to begin with?  Why do you have all these empty `if` blocks?  It's not clear to me what logic you're trying to express here.

Comment: the constant y = 0 was me trying to reset the y im fairly new to coding and not entirely sure how i would do rest it. Basically im trying to have the code check if something has been destroyed and once all of the objects attached to the main object are destroyed it creates a collider componet on the main gameObject. I made it a loop to constantly check if those objects are still there or destroyed.

Comment: This is what the debugger you have at your fingertips is for.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Instead of this: `if (GameObject.Find("right") != null) {} else { y++; }` you could do this: `if (GameObject.Find("right") == null) {y++;}` That doesn't solve what you're asking but if that helps with `if/then` then it's good, else it wasn't. Haha, I made a joke.

Comment: @ScottHannen Good point but i think he want to increment `y` when and object is found so it must be: `if (GameObject.Find("right") != null) {y++;}`. Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
IEnumerator checkTurrets() {
    while (true) {
        if (GameObject.Find("right") != null && GameObject.Find("left") != null && GameObject.Find("bottom") != null) 
        { 
            SphereCollider sc = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof (SphereCollider)) as SphereCollider; 
        } 
    }
}
```

I am assuming you want to execute the statement when you find all three objects.